# Why can't I reset my array with setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, setstate

In my camera component, I want to upload the photos to a storage bucket every 3 photos. I use state in react to save my image blobs to an array. Everything works perfectly for the first 3 photos but afterward, I am not able to reset my array to be empty again and a seemingly random number of photos is uploaded to my bucket.

```js
  let [blobs, setBlobs] = useState([]);

  const capturePhoto = async () => {
    const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
    fetch(photo.path)
      .then(res => {
        setBlobs([...blobs, res._bodyBlob]);
        console.log('blobs', blobs.length, blobs);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
    checkLength();
  };

  const checkLength = async () => {
    if (blobs.length >= 2) {
      // upload files to a folder with the current date in a firebase cloud bucket
      const datestring = new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE');
      blobs.forEach((blob, i) => {
        uploadFile(blob, datestring + '/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg');
      });
      // reset state
      setBlobs([]);
      sendNotification('Photos uploaded');
      toggleDialog();
    }
  };
```

I console logged my array and the size only increases. Also, it starts console logging with zero although I already added an element likely because `setState()` is asynchronous.
I tried to await the reset by wrapping it in a promise, but that sadly did not work either.
How can I upload the blobs to the cloud once there are 3 of them and reset the list afterward?

Comment: Try `setBlobs([]);`, instead of `setBlobs([], sendNotification('Photos uploaded'));`

Comment: Only class based components use a setState form that accepts a second callback. Also logging right after a setState call will always print the un-updated value, the new value won't be available until the next render cycle. see [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: @admcfajn I already did. Didn't work sadly.

Comment: @pilchard The second callback does work in both cases.

Comment: `useState`'s setter function doesn't accept a second callback. Any side-effects should be handled manually in the handler (not relying on updated state values), or in a `useEffect` triggered by the state change. You aren't passing a callback, you are simply calling a function inside another function's arguments

Comment: @pilchard so how do I fix the setBlobs([]) then? May I provide you with any additional information?

Comment: It looks like you'll need a `useEffect` dependent on `blobs` that runs your `checkLength` function. Since the `setBlobs` call in that function is wrapped in a condition you won't be at risk of an infinite loop.

Comment: The code/description may be incomplete or based on false assumptions, but as pointed out above this is almost certainly a duplicate of [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193).  At the very least, when you call `checkLength()` then it won't have the updated `blobs` from just before calling it. `setBlobs([])` certainly *does* set the state to an empty array, but if you're trying to observe that before the next render then state won't be updated yet. And state updates aren't promise-based, so there's no chance of awaiting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like three things:

1. The fetch call is not awaited, `checkLength` is called before the fetch completes.
2. You don't get the new value of `setState` until the next render. This is a fundamental idea of React (debatable whether it's a good idea), state values are immutable during a render. `setState` just gives the next immutable state that will be used by the next render.
3. When `setState` depends on the previous state, you should pass a callback to `setState` instead of using the current value directly. As an example, say you have an empty array, you call fetch once, then again before the first one completes. Both of these `setState` calls would be referencing the empty array when doing `...blobs`. By passing a callback, `setState` gets the most recent value passed in as a parameter. More info: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate

Easiest solution is to pass the array as a parameter to `checkLength` inside of the `setState` callback.

Here's with `.then()` as in the question:

```js
  const capturePhoto = async () => {
    const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
    fetch(photo.path)
      .then(res => {
        setBlobs(prev => {
          const newBlobs = [...prev, res._bodyBlob];
          console.log('blobs', newBlobs.length, newBlobs);
          checkLength(newBlobs);
          return newBlobs;
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
  };
```

and here's with `async` `await`

```js
  const capturePhoto = async () => {
    const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
    const res = await fetch(photo.path).catch(console.error);
    if (!res) return;
    setBlobs(prev => {
      const newBlobs = [...prev, res._bodyBlob];
      console.log('blobs', newBlobs.length, newBlobs);
      checkLength(newBlobs);
      return newBlobs;
    });
  };
```

`checkLength`

```js
  const checkLength = async (newBlobs) => {
    if (newBlobs.length >= 2) {
      // upload files to a folder with the current date in a firebase cloud bucket
      const datestring = new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE');
      newBlobs.forEach((blob, i) => {
        uploadFile(blob, datestring + '/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg');
      });
      // reset state
      setBlobs([]);
      sendNotification('Photos uploaded');
      toggleDialog();
    }
  };
```

Comment: So the reason was that I only executed my if Statement on the next render?

Comment: @Felkru not quite, no. The if statement was executing before the code housed in `.then()`. That was only issue 1. Issue 2 was that you were not referencing the most recent value of the array when copying it for `setState`. Issue 3 was that you were not referencing the most recent value of the array in your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

So it does come down to how your code executes, specifically the `asyncronous nature of setState` so what you can do is use the `callback form of setState`. Here is an example:

```
setBlobs(prevBlobs => [...prevBlobs, res._bodyBlob]);
```

Here's a complete example with the rest of the code:

```
const capturePhoto = async () => {
  const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
  fetch(photo.path)
    .then(res => {
      setBlobs(prevBlobs => [...prevBlobs, res._bodyBlob]);
      console.log('blobs', blobs.length, blobs);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err', err);
    });
  checkLength();
};

const checkLength = async () => {
  if (blobs.length >= 2) {
    // upload files to a folder with the current date in a firebase cloud bucket
    const datestring = new Date().toLocaleString('de-DE');
    blobs.forEach((blob, i) => {
      uploadFile(blob, datestring + '/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg');
    });
    // reset state
    setBlobs([]);
    sendNotification('Photos uploaded');
    toggleDialog();
  }
};
```